# Downgrade from IE9 to IE8 on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, installation, internet-explorer-8

I upgraded my IE version to IE 9 in Windows 7 Enterprise. When I felt some compatibility issue with a web application that I created, I turned off the IE 9. Now I have to install the previous version (ie., IE 8) on my Windows 7 Enterprise PC. How can I do it?

Comment: Solved. Check the following http://techdows.com/2010/09/how-to-downgrade-from-ie9-to-ie8.html

Comment: You can put your comment as an answer, but also include the steps necessary to downgrade and not just paste the link. Then you can accept it in two days, that way the question will be closed.

Comment: Downgrading from IE9 to IE8

1.Close all programs, click Start and click Control Panel.

2.Click “Uninstall a Program” under Programs category.

3.Click “View installed updates” option in the task pane.

4.Now select Windows Internet Explorer 9 shown under Microsoft Windows updates and click Uninstall and follow the instructions on the screen. IE9 uninstall process lasts for minimum 3 minutes and you will be able to access Internet Explorer 8 as usual after restart.

Comment: No, I mean, as an **answer** below, where it says "Answer your Question" ...

Comment: Once you've posted an answer here, do flag, I'll delete mine

Comment: @MuhammedRaufK -> you're supposed to post an answer in the answers section before flagging.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Downgrading from IE9 to IE8

1. Close all programs, click Start and click Control Panel.
2. Click “Uninstall a Program” under Programs category.
3. Click “View installed updates” option in the task pane.
4. Now select Windows Internet Explorer 9 shown under Microsoft Windows updates and click Uninstall and follow the instructions on the screen. IE9 uninstall process lasts for minimum 3 minutes and you will be able to access Internet Explorer 8 as usual after restart

Comment: You may need to manually add IE8 afterwards if it wasn't already on, in which case go into the "Turn Windows features on or off" section of Programs and Features and click the box next to IE8.  My complete steps: "turn off" ie9, "uninstall" IE9 update, then "turn on" ie8.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative in Windows 7, you can select "Turn Windows Features on or Off" from Programs and Features, this will pop open another window, then Uncheck Internet Explorer 9 from the list and hit OK, this will not uninstall it but just disable it, leaving IE8.

.

[image]

Comment: Nope. It will disable IE altogether.

Comment: I confirm that this answer is not valid, this option just uninstalls Internet Explorer, it does not revert to a previous version.