# Install IE8 on Windows 7 VM

Tags: windows-7, windows, browser, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I created a Windows 7 x64 VM on Windows Azure but it came with IE11.

So I removed IE11 from "Turn on and off Windows Features". After reboot, it still doesn't give me an option to rollback to IE8.

I found a download link from Microsoft for IE8 but they are not for Windows 7.

Comment: I would imagine this could be a solution: http://superuser.com/a/291565/259665

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, I tried that but the problem is that in "Turn Windows features on or off" window, it only has IE11, not IE8 even after reboot.

Comment: When you removed IE11 what version IE was installed if anything or did that just uninstall IE entirely?  Your likely going to end up having to install Windows 7 yourself if you want IE8

Comment: @Ramhound, it's a canned VM from Microsoft Azure so I don't know what IE they had before IE11.

Comment: Did you try launching IE after you Uninstalled IE11?

Comment: @Downvoter, why is this not a good question?

Comment: @Ramhound, I realized uninstall a feature is different from uninstall an update. The correct way is to uninstall IE9, 10 and 11 updates rather than uninstall "IE11 feature" which disabled IE all together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're digging in the wrong place :-)  If you remove it from Windows Features, it simply removes Internet Explorer entirely.  You don't want that.

Instead, go to Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Uninstall a Program.  Then click the "View Installed Updates" link on the left.  You should see IE 11 in that list.  Remove that, and it will roll you back to whatever was on it before IE 11 got installed.

Worst case scenario, you'll have to do this several times (once to IE 10, then IE 9, then finally, IE 8)

Comment: this solution worked, why would anyone downvote it?

Comment: No idea. I upvoted it for you.